# Prove the inequality involving integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

How would you show that (if $x\gt0$):
$$\int_x^1 \frac{dt}{1 + t^2} = \int_1^{1/x} \frac{dt}{1 + t^2}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Make a change of variable $t=\frac {1} {u}$ on the left hand side and see what happens for the integral over $u$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Note that:

$$\int \frac{dt}{1 + t^2} = \arctan(t)$$

Hence your formula simplifies to

$$\arctan(1) - \arctan(x) = \arctan(\frac{1}{x}) - \arctan(1)$$
$$ \Leftrightarrow 2\arctan(1) = \arctan(x) + \arctan(\frac{1}{x})$$

Calculate the values of both sides (the right hand side is a special 'well-known' identity) to show that both sides are equal.

Answer (score -1):

*put*$$ z=\frac{1}{t} $$ *then the integrals limit changes and then omitting negative sign you get the answer*